# Where to find docs for TRANSFORM_OT_shrink_fatten?

Tags: python

I have a python script I made two years ago. It doesn't work anymore. So I thought I would upgrade it to work with the latest version of Blender.

The failing line is:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(MESH_OT_extrude_region={...}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={...})
```

And I went and looked it up in the docs:

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_faces_move

```
bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_shrink_fatten(MESH_OT_extrude_region=None, TRANSFORM_OT_shrink_fatten=None)
```

But where do I find what goes into the TRANSFORM_OT_shrink_fatten dictionary?
I have tried to google it. Nothing current comes up (that I can find).
If I search for it in the docs, only the page above comes up.

Or am I approaching this the wrong way? If I do the extrude command and copy the code from the scripting tab, it isn't doing the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TRANSFORM_OT_shrink_fatten` is the class name of the operator `bpy.ops.transform.shrink_fatten`, which you can find the documentation for by following the link :

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.transform.html#bpy.ops.transform.shrink_fatten

Here's a list of the arguments :

- `value` (float in [-inf, inf], (optional)) – Offset
- `use_even_offset` (boolean, (optional)) – Offset Even, Scale the offset to give more even thickness
- `mirror` (boolean, (optional)) – Mirror Editing
- `use_proportional_edit` (boolean, (optional)) – Proportional Editing
- `proportional_edit_falloff` (enum in Proportional Falloff Items, (optional)) – Proportional Falloff, Falloff type for proportional editing mode
- `proportional_size` (float in [1e-06, inf], (optional)) – Proportional Size
- `use_proportional_connected` (boolean, (optional)) – Connected
- `use_proportional_projected` (boolean, (optional)) – Projected (2D)
- `snap` (boolean, (optional)) – Use Snapping Options
- `release_confirm` (boolean, (optional)) – Confirm on Release, Always confirm operation when releasing button
- `use_accurate` (boolean, (optional)) – Accurate, Use accurate transformation
- `alt_navigation` (boolean, (optional)) – Transform Navigation with Alt

Comment: Thank you. This helped. It's strange however. When I lookup the extrude_and_move command in the docs. It says the second parameter is TRANSFORM_OT_shrink_fatten. But when I copy the command from blender it says TRANSFORM_OT_translate. Bug?